# Attach Printable View PDF as an attachment in Standard Object

Tags: apex, attachment

I have a requirement of attaching the Printable View of a standard detail page to the Attachments of a salesforce object.I have written code in developer console but the PDF saved is not opening.

```
 PageReference newPage = new PageReference('/0019000000LAanJ/p');
  blob blobFormPDF = newPage.getContent(); 


  attachment attach = new attachment();
  attach.ParentId = '0019000000LAanJ';
  attach.Name = 'test';
  attach.Body = blobFormPDF;

  insert attach;
```

Answer (score 2):

Printable View is just an HTML page, it is not PDF format.  You would need to write a Visualforce page to display all the desired sections and fields and render this as a PDF.  See [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_renderas.htm).